# Can RackSpace cloud images be downloaded and used on a private cloud inside your local network?

Tags: cloud, amazon-ec2

I've read that for example Ubuntu Enterprise Could images can be loaded from a private cloud residing on your local network to Amazon EC2. Or you can create a image on Amazon EC2 and then download it and use the image on your private cloud.

Is there something similar that you can do on RackSpace cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your store your image on Cloud Files, you can download it (access the "cloudservers" container in Cloud Files via your Control Panel or third-party app).  If you're running your own OpenStack-based cloud, it may be possible to then use that image locally.

As for going the other way (using a local image on the Rackspace Cloud), I don't think that they currently support that.  You could upload files into Cloud Files, but there's no way to "register" an image like you can on EC2.

Comment: and how do you store an image on cloud files?